# why I don't get the same result from my hashed password with sha512?

Tags: php, hash, sha512

I am very new in programming, I just start in last April and today I am facing a problem, because in my login file I call a

`$hashedPassword = $securityHelper->hashPassword($_POST['password'], $userFinded->getSalt());`

to hash my password and to compare with the hashed password in my database.
But I always got different result like here:

```
Password: Michelle123
Hached BD Password: 9705f99f231cef89289a57db52e202e4f9b221144c500734d3beb0d2eaf2371e3f2c203f914c1616383eee58548e3964d6402cb779041cc07bb2683b7110f3e5
Hached Password: 2085f93e3c4a241cc3f17327c1bf01f87330c9bdf03f8ec6fd6a04d6a62454ea6961aef395b08b5eac0d5c63ed49c1fcd2328b455d402bd623fb2f75908c8ee8
Salt: h7b867Xxk9WE2CugPT6TKJ6nHkvRhH1BMgC3B69fG5xfv47nZB
```

I have looked in internet but I didn't find anything yet.

=> In my login file

```
$securityHelper = new SecurityHelper();

$userManager = new UserManager();

$userFinded = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

// Hache le mot de passe
$hashedPassword = $securityHelper->hashPassword($_POST['password'], $userFinded->getSalt());

if ($userFinded) {
    echo 'Password: '.$_POST['password'];
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'Hached BD Password: '.$userFinded->getPassword();
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'Hached Password: '.$hashedPassword;
    echo '</br>';
    echo 'Salt: '.$userFinded->getSalt();
    echo '</br>';
}
```

=> This is my SecurityHelper class:

```
class SecurityHelper {

    private $pepper = "dfau0f90230932Ff@#UNKu9032%u032f9uf03209buguWETQTTwe";

    public function randomString() {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $string = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            $charNum = mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1);
            $string .= $chars[$charNum];
        }
        return $string;
    }

    public function hashPassword($plainPassword, $userSalt) {
        //hache le mot de passe d'une manière lente, avec 2 chaînes concaténées
        $hashedPassword = hash("sha512", $plainPassword);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
            $hashedPassword = hash("sha512", $this->pepper . $hashedPassword . $userSalt);
        }
        return $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

=> Here is my UserManager Class function

```
class UserManager extends EntityManager {

    public function save(User $user) {

        //requête d'insertion, avec paramètre nommés
        $sql = "INSERT INTO vi_users
                (email, password, nom, prenom, salt, token, dateCreated, dateModified)
                VALUES
                (:email, :password, :nom, :prenom, :token, :salt, :dateCreated, :dateModified)";

        // Envoit la requête à MySQL
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);

        // Assigne des valeurs à chaque paramètre nommé
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $user->getEmail());
        $stmt->bindValue(":password", $user->getPassword());
        $stmt->bindValue(":nom", $user->getNom());
        $stmt->bindValue(":prenom", $user->getPrenom());
        $stmt->bindValue(":salt", $user->getSalt());
        $stmt->bindValue(":token", $user->getToken());
        $stmt->bindValue(":dateCreated", $user->getDateCreated()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $stmt->bindValue(":dateModified", $user->getDateModified()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

        //finalement, exécute la requête
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    // Compte le nombre total d'utilisateur dans la bdd et retourne ce nombre
    public function countUsers() {
        include_once ("models/User.php");

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vi_users";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $usersNumber = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        return $usersNumber;
    }

    // Récupère (et retourne) tous les utilisateurs
    function findAllUsers() {
        include_once ("models/User.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vi_users ORDER BY user ASC";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");

        return $users;
    }


    public function findUserById($id) {
        include_once ("models/User.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vi_users 
                WHERE id_user = :id";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetchObject("User");
        return $user;
    }

    public function findUserByEmail($email) {
        include_once ("models/User.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vi_users 
                WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetchObject("User");
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share also your UserManager class?

Comment: Probably the problem is that your `$userSalt` is not always the same for this user (a change in DB?). Or another possibility is that your stored hashed password were calculated different than the process that you use to validate it.

Comment: the `$userSalt` is generated and stored in the DB, it is always the same.
Also the stored function is calculated with the same fonction `public function hashPassword($plainPassword, $userSalt)`

Answer (score 0):

A friend finally helped me to find the error in my code, and it was in my `UserManager.php`,
when I was storing a new user, I made mistake and I inverse the `:token` and `:salt`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vi_users
        (email, password, nom, prenom, salt, token, dateCreated, dateModified)
        VALUES
        (:email, :password, :nom, :prenom, :token, :salt, :dateCreated, :dateModified)";
```

After changing this part my code works fine and I am very happy, thank you for your help.

```
Password:           Azerty123
Hached DB Password: 0efbadc9d0c32ca1c4c0421d212cc38cad2d2bfa8815faf18595470c50dbcce92283e3ff40170ada6cd2354345b8a48d26c32cd7c763ff79ed4b2ebb10c0e02d
Hached Password:    0efbadc9d0c32ca1c4c0421d212cc38cad2d2bfa8815faf18595470c50dbcce92283e3ff40170ada6cd2354345b8a48d26c32cd7c763ff79ed4b2ebb10c0e02d
Salt:               YTXnJeo5NL8klA5PaQ1Hd7ShmuWs6UyuO4gWftBwKaIFpKQNNl
```